# Get date of 3 years after the user entered date using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, date

I have a date input as
     `<input type="date" name="date_register" id="date_register" value="date" />`
I want to print the date after 3 years of the user entered date. How can i get using PHP?

Comment: You need to provide more details: where you are saving dates , how you are going to retrieve them ...

Comment: I'm using an AJAX code to get the user input date.

Comment: Thats means after entering date in the input data is sent to a PHP file using ajax.right?

Comment: yes, input date is sent using Ajax

Comment: What is the format of date Y-m-d or Y/m/d

Comment: This is date input in HTML 5. The date format shown in the date input box is 'mm/dd/yyyy'. But when the date is printed it will be printed in the format of 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: Ok i will post the code in 5 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php
    $date = isset($_REQUEST['date_register']) ? $_REQUEST['date_register'] : date('Y/m/d');

    $three_yrs = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date .' +3 years'));
    Echo $three_yrs;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the PHP [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.  Here is an example that should help you get started:

```
$date = new DateTime($_POST['date_register'];
$date->modify('+3 years');

var_dump($date);
echo $date->format('F j, Y');
```

Comment: Either use the object-oriented approach `$date = new DateTime(...); $date->modify(...);` or the procedural `$date = date_create(...); $date = date_modify($date, ...);`. Don't mix and match between the procedural and object-oriented approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //i assume that your field name is date_register and method used is post
 $unix_date_after_add_3_years = strtotime($_POST["date_register"]." +3 years",);
 //now formatting the result to be for example 17-9-2014 using function date
 echo date("Y-m-d",$unix_date_after_add_3_years);
```